# How can I prevent Picasa from automatically capturing a screenshot to a folder?

Tags: screenshot, picasa

Anyone know how to prevent picasa from capturing screenshots and saving them automatically in a folder?

This only happens when Picasa is running.

Answer (score 1):

Google Support Forum has: [Screenshots constantly saving -- how do I stop this feature?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=0912a513053c63d8&hl=en)

So, turns out Google released the screenshot feature and then bugged in some way (I expect this to be solved by now, are you using the latest Picasa edition?).

There is another reference to the forum answer by `Jeffery Klassen` at Lifehacker,
[Stop Picasa from Filling Your Hard Disk with Unwanted Screenshots](http://lifehacker.com/5520271/stop-picasa-from-filling-your-hard-disk-with-unwanted-screenshots).
<sup>Since this is a relatively recent post (Apr 2010), I guess Picasa may not have have this fixed yet).</sup>

Comment: thansk nik, i am using the latest, 3.8 for pc, but its still doing it...i'll check this forum thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

A bit more detail for XP Pro/Vista Pro [Ed. Note: Works fine in Windows 7]

1. Locate the screen shot folder that Picasa creates. Something like `My Docs\Pictures\Picasa\Screen Captures`
2. Right Click on it > Properties > Security Tab
3. Go to Advanced > Then in the permissions tab click Edit.
4. Un-check the "Include inheritable permissions from this objects parent"
5. A pop up will ask you if you want to do this and if you want to copy or remove the permissions. In this case you want to "remove" them.
6. Apply everything and check that you no longer have access to the folder.

For XP Home/Vista Home

1. Go to this link on information about how to get a security tab, so you can edit these settings. The easiest is to boot into safemode.
2. Follow the directions for XP Pro.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly, why have you been downvoted though.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this happen and the solution is very  simple.
This is due to a print screen key stuck on the keyboard. Just press once and see, it should stop.
IF not check the print screen key. It must be stuck physically.
Very simple solution:
http://day2dayexps.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-stop-picasa-saving-screenshots.html